SciFi movie from the 90s with robot in space
Many many years ago i watched a Sci-Fi movie where in the beginning a (alien?) robot was on a spaceship. I think it was a transporter heading to a planet.
In the middle of the movie the driver/captain (wtf) of the spaceship fights against the robot, but the robot later manages to stay outside of the ship.
At the end of the movie the transporter collides with the planet (open ended).
I saw it in TV, in color.
The language was german.

"I saw it in TV, in color. The language was german." - That doesn't say much, though, as nearly everything on German TV is in German language. Any idea if it was originally from a different country/language?

Sounds vaguely like John Carpenter's "Dark Star". Is there anything else you can think of to describe it?

@mungflesh its not dark star

@NapoleonWilson i dunno

This seems very unclear.

Saturn 3? There are 3 characters, one man (Adam/Kirk Douglas), one woman (Alex/Farah Fawcett), one robot. The robot goes looney, and the man does fight him. I think they were on a remote outpost, but I think there was also a transport, definitely one in the beginning and end of the movie at least.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079285/

Could it be Disney's The Black Hole - which had robots central to the plot - friendly robots V.I.N.CENT and Bob, and antagonistic robot Maximillian.
In the end the large ship in the story crashes into the Black Hole.
Here is a youtube video of a battle between the robots

Could it be Stanley Kubrick's "2001: A Space Odyssey"?
Many years old, definitely has been translated to German, with a man fighting a robot (H.A.L) on a spaceship near the middle of the movie, and the spaceship eventually colliding with planet (sort of)...

sadly no :( ...
